# Temporarily deactivate physical collision between two Nodes(Swift 2, IOS)

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift2

I'm using **SpriteKit**, and I'm having trouble getting one of my objects to shoot out another object, without colliding with it at the moment that it shoots it. However, as soon as they are no longer within range of contact each-other, I want them to be able to contact with each-other for the rest of the game.

Here is what I have tried-

```
    var allCategory: UInt32  = 1;
    var nillCategory: UInt32  = 2;
    var bufferNode: SKNode?

    bufferNode = self.childNodeWithName("player")
    bufferNode!.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = nillCategory;
    bufferNode!.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = nillCategory;
    shootNewPlayer(touchLocation)
    runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(1),SKAction.runBlock(removeBuffer)]))
}
func removeBuffer(){
    bufferNode!.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = allCategory;
    bufferNode!.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = allCategory;
}
```

By default, all my objects in the scene have a collisionBitMask and categoryBitMask of "allCategory." My solution was to temporarily change its categories to nill. This had absolutely no affect. I also want to avoid this solution since for 1 second the player would no longer interact with objects, which could cause bugs (With the code above it still interacts).

Any ideas on how I can get the object to shoot a new player without it flying off in a bazaar direction? Thanks!

Comment: Set the `collisionBitMask` to 0 to disable collisions and use a `waitForDuration`/`runBlock` `SKAction` sequence to reenable.

Comment: You should reserve nilCategory to be 0, and allCategory to be 0xFFFFFFFF.

Comment: I up-voted your question, but could you possibly include a screenshot or two?  It would help visual folks like me understand your needs.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off object2 collision by default. (Do this with collisionBitMask = 0)

Enable object contactBitMask with the flag for object1.

On the didEndContact Method,  enable the collision object2 for object1 when the condition of object1 contacting object2 is met.

This will allow you to avoid things like timers and checking the update loop constantly.

In English, you are saying: When object 2 no longer is touching object 1, object 2 is now able to collide with object 1.

Depending on circumstance, you may want to remove the contact test after you enable collision

Comment: Let say `object1`'s category is 1 and `object2`'s category is 2 and the app already added 20 `object2`s to the scene. When the app shoots another `object2`, you set `object1`'s `contactTestBitMask` to 2, right? Well, Sprite Kit now has to check for contacts between `object1` *and* 21 `object2`s in the scene (at ~60 times a sec). And if another `object2` contacts `object1` before `didEndContact` is called, the code needs to somehow determine which `object2` should have its collision bits enabled.

Comment: For this scenario, you would need 21 objects 1s firing off 21 object 2s at the same time, and  an object 1 would have to be inside another object1, since you would turn off contact after object 2 has left object 1.   To combat that issue, just do a name check.

Comment: with your situation, your object 1 cannot even move, otherwise you can hit a situation where object 1 is still inside object 2

Comment: If `object1`'s `contactTestBitMask` is set to 2, Sprite Kit needs to check if a contact is made with *all* nodes with category = 2.

Comment: yes, but once object2 has left object1, you turn off the contact checking

Comment: A timer approach assumes the velocity of the projectile is (much) faster than the object doing the shooting, which is true for most games.

Comment: Not safe to make assumptions, we have no idea what the intent is of any reader looking at this question

Comment: You can compute the timer's duration using the velocities of the shooter and projectile.

Comment: only if the shooter is stationary or at a static speed, what if the shooter moves forward at a variable rate, with the initial shot being stationary, but then increases right after the shot to 2x the speed of the projectile.  Timer expires, shooter is still inside bullet

Comment: Hey ok I tried this method but my only problem is that if object1 is up against a wall or something and the player shoots directly at the wall, then the projectile goes through the wall. I need ONLY the collision between the player and the projectile to be disabled.

Comment: Then do not set it to 0. Set it to all but player

Comment: How would I set it to all but player without then making the player not interact with the world? If objects with the same collisionbitmask collide then one of the two would have to have a different mask then everything else right? Or unless you can give it two bit masks...?

Comment: You are allowed 32 categories,  set your player to collide with walls but not object 2,  then when object 2 is not touching set player to collide with wall and object 2

Comment: Can you show me the exact code for that? I only know how to give an object one collisionbitmask.

Comment: Collisionbitmask = mask1 | mask2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101643/discussion-between-marshalld-and-knight0fdragon).